# The radius of convergence of $\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$ where $0 < \alpha \leq |a_{n}| \leq \beta$ for $n \geq 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Since $|a_{n}||x|^{n} \leq \beta|x|^{n},$ since $\beta^{1/n}|x| = |x| + o(1)\big|_{n \to \infty}$, and since $\sum \beta |x|^{n}$ converges if $|x| < 1,$ it follows that $\sum|a_{n}||x|^{n}$ converges if $|x| < 1.$ Thus 1 is the radius of convergence of $\sum a_{n}x^{n}.$

However, I suspect my argument above because nowhere it uses the condition $\alpha \leq |a_{n}|$.

Comment: From the $0\lt \alpha\le a_n$ you can show that the radius of convergence is $\ge 1$. The $\beta$ upper bound tells you the radius of convergence is $\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks. So 1 is the radius of convergence, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. We could also write that $\alpha^{1/n}\le a_n^{1/n}\le \beta^{1/n}$.  Both $\alpha^{1/n}$ and $\beta^{1/n}$ have limit $1$, so by Squeezing so does $a_n^{1/n}$, so the radius of convergence is $1$.